# TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition doesn't animate scaling

Tags: android

`TransitionManager` suppose to auto-animate all changes in container after `beginDelayedTransition()`. Executing this code does nothing:

```
fooView.setScaleY(0);
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootView);
fooView.setScaleY(1);
```

---

**Question:** Why doesn't this code work? Doesn't `beginDelayedTransition` support scale animations?

---

**Edit:** to be more precise the element just "jumps" into full scale without transition animation. This happens only with the scaling, since the same works fine if visibility or transform is used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After long 3 days experimenting, reading, asking - I have finally came to solution and understanding WHY. So, the **short answer is**:

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootView, new Slide());
fooView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

With introduction of Material Design and `TransitionManager` - Android handles how things should be done by itself. In my case I wanted a view to slide from the bottom - so I tried to mimic that functionality using `scale` and setting the pivot point and `visibility`, but in fact it could be done much simpler.

The **long answer is**: `TransitionManager` doesn't have scaling supported. If you want to use it for some reason - you would have to write your own animations or use a 3rd party libraries. But when Google created the Material Design, they wanted you to follow new patterns - so try to forget about scaling for the sake of scaling, think about "changing bounds".

**Edit:** After info **pskink** from it seems you can actually animate the scaling (using ChangeTransform - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/package-summary.html). Or write your own `Transition`.

Comment: `"The long answer is: TransitionManager doesn't have scaling supported."`, no, it all depends what `android.transition.Transition` you will use

Comment: https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50 - "Scale: This one is not actually a part of Transitions API".

Comment: `cd <sdkroot>/sources/android-25/android/transition; grep -r scaleY .` and besides, you can also write your own custom `android.transition.Transition` and do whatever you want there

Comment: its fine that `ChangeTransform` worked for you because, as you saw (reading `ChangeTransform` sources) writing a new `Transition` is not an easy task...